# what data structure is used to store graph in networkX?

Tags: graph, social-networking, networkx

I'm using networkX for social graph analysis. I'm wondering how this library achieves such performance.
Does it use adjacent list or matrix to store the graph or used graph database like neo4j to store the graph?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From 
http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/introduction.html

*The graph internal data structures are based on an adjacency list representation and implemented using Python dictionary datastructures. The graph adjaceny structure is implemented as a Python dictionary of dictionaries; the outer dictionary is keyed by nodes to values that are themselves dictionaries keyed by neighboring node to the edge attributes associated with that edge. This “dict-of-dicts” structure allows fast addition, deletion, and lookup of nodes and neighbors in large graphs. The underlying datastructure is accessed directly by methods (the programming interface “API”) in the class definitions. All functions, on the other hand, manipulate graph-like objects solely via those API methods and not by acting directly on the datastructure. This design allows for possible replacement of the ‘dicts-of-dicts’-based datastructure with an alternative datastructure that implements the same methods.*

Comment: Less aged link: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/introduction.html#networkx-basics